# Why isn't my new Magento theme showing when I activate it?

Tags: php, magento2

I have created these directories:

```
-app
  -design
    -frontend
      -vendor
        -theme
            -theme.xml
          -Media
            -preview.jpg
```

The theme is loaded in the backend design list, but when I activate it then nothing shows on the frontend.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from [Magento.StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94541/theme-is-not-showing-in-admin-panel-list-magento2/94546#94546):

> `app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/theme.xml`
>
> ```
> <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
>      <title>My theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
>      <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
>      <media>
>          <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
>      </media>
>  </theme>
> ```
>
> `app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/composer.json`
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "magento/theme-frontend-blank",
>     "description": "N/A",
>     "require": {
>         "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
>         "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
>         "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
>     },
>     "type": "magento2-theme",
>     "version": "100.0.1",
>     "license": [
>         "OSL-3.0",
>         "AFL-3.0"
>     ],
>     "autoload": {
>         "files": [
>             "registration.php"
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> `app/design/frontend/Magento/mytheme/registration.php`
>
> ```
> <?php
> /**
> * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
> * See COPYING.txt for license details.
> */
> \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
>     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
>     'frontend/Magento/mytheme',
>     __DIR__
> );
> ```

Comment: i hv done this all but when i debug from configuration then no file is showing from app/design all files are coming from vendor/design/ or in some cases app/code/design/

Comment: `bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` did you deploy content?

Comment: i changed my project in a developer mode in magentoce2 folder after doing it my all other project in other folders showing vendor/design/

Comment: go to directory and deploy only that project content

Comment: i did it many times. i worked in 7 folders now its turning to 8th. one more problem i am geting.

Comment: i attached custom `style.css` file in `configuration` web tab. but its not working neither magento own font icon working.

Comment: adding css directly not work for magento 2. copy file from. i prefer read this discussion  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98099/how-to-create-magento2-custom-theme-design/98101#98101

Comment: i did it sorry for late